# SQL: avoiding hard-coding or magic numbers

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

**Question:** What are some other strategies on avoiding magic numbers or hard-coded values in your SQL scripts or stored procedures?

Consider a stored procedure whose job is to check/update a value of a record based on its `StatusID` or some other FK lookup table or range of values.

Consider a `Status` table where the ID is most important, as it's a FK to another table:

[image]

The SQL scripts that are to be avoided are *something like*:

```
DECLARE  @ACKNOWLEDGED tinyint

SELECT  @ACKNOWLEDGED = 3   --hardcoded BAD

UPDATE  SomeTable
SET     CurrentStatusID = @ACKNOWLEDGED
WHERE   ID = @SomeID
```

The problem here is that this is not portable and is explicitly dependent on the hard-coded value. Subtle defects exist when deploying this to another environment with identity inserts off.

Also trying to avoid a `SELECT` based on the text description/name of the status:

```
UPDATE  SomeTable
SET     CurrentStatusID = (SELECT ID FROM [Status] WHERE [Name] = 'Acknowledged')
WHERE   ID = @SomeID
```

**Question:** What are some other strategies on avoiding magic numbers or hard-coded values in your SQL scripts or stored procedures?

Some other thoughts on how to achieve this:

- add a new `bit` column (named like 'IsAcknowledged') and sets of rules where there can be only one row with a value of `1`. This would help in finding the unique row: `SELECT ID FROM [Status] WHERE [IsAcknowledged] = 1)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At some level, there's going to be some "hard coding" of values. The idea of eliminating them comes from two sides:

1. Making the code more readable (i.e., saying `'Acknowledged'` rather than `3` is *probably* going to make your intentions more obvious to the reader.
2. Making the code more dynamic, where one function can take a parameter rather than several functions that don't (this is a simplification obviously, but the meaning should be fairly self-evident anyway)

Making `bit` columns for various states can be a good or bad idea; it really just depends on the data. If the data goes through various "stages" (Received, Acknowledged, Under Review, Rejected, Accepted, Responded, etc.) then that approach quickly scales itself out of viability (not to mention the irritating process of having to ensure that *only one* of the columns is set to 1 at any given time). If, on the other hand, the state is really as simple as you describe, then doing that can make the code more readable and indexes perform better.

The biggest no-no in hard coding values is *hard coding values that reference other entities* (in other words, hard coding the primary key for a corresponding object). The string `'Acknowledged`' is still a hard-coded value, it's just more transparent in its meaning and it isn't a reference to something else. For me, it boils down to this: **if you can (reasonably) look it up, do it**. If you can't (or if something makes it an unreasonable task either from a performance or maintainability perspective), hard code it. Using this, you can look up the value of 3 by using `Acknowledged`; you can't look up `Acknowledged` from anything else.

Answer (score 14):

For situations like your status table, I create what I call "static" data sets. These tables contain data that

- Is set and defined upon creation,
- Never ever changes, and
- Is ALWAYS the same, from database instance to database instance, with *no* exceptions

That is, at the same time you create the table, you populate it as well, using a script to ensure that the values are always the same. Thereafter, no matter what where or when the database, you will *know* what the values are, and can hard-code accordingly and appropriately. (I would never use surrogate keys or the identity column property in these situations.)

You do not have to use numbers, you can use strings -- or binaries or dates, or whatever is simplest, easiest, and most appropriate. (When I can, I use char strings--and not varchars--such as "RCVD", "DLVR", ACKN", and so forth are easier hard-coded values than, say, 0, 2, and 3.)

This system works for non-extensible sets of values. If these values can be modified (such that 0 no longer means "acknowledged", then you have a security access problem. If you have a system where new codes can be added by users, then you have a different and tricky design issue to resolve.

Comment: Agreed. In these kinds of cases I create a StatusCd column of some sort whose value never changes. This way it can port across systems, yet be understandable just by looking at the code value.

Comment: Do you make this human readable unique value the primary key of the table?  Or do you still use a integer as the primary key?

Comment: I use the unique value (essentially, the natrual key); adding a surrogate key to such a table is utterly pointless.

Comment: So you put 'DLVR' into the only column in the enum table and then put 'DLVR' in each column that references it?  Sounds like a space/performance nightmare vs just `FooTypeID IN (1,3)`.

Comment: (Only just noticed the prior comment) --  Nightmare? Not very likely. char(4) takes 4 bytes and int takes 4 bytes, so you're not saving space or memory usage. Even if you make it a tinyint (which you should) its only 1 byte, saving you 3 bytes per row. 100,000,000 rows is 300MB of "extra" space, which is pretty much invisible (in both time and space) these days. Final point: as per general industry standards, I would not use this as a key in a data warehouse, but rather maintain the standard fact/dimension surrogate key model.

Answer (score 12):

I recently figured out that magic numbers can be [implemented by views](http://devio.wordpress.com/2009/11/23/constants-in-ms-sql-server/):

```
CREATE VIEW V_Execution_State AS
SELECT 10 AS Pending, 20 AS Running, 30 AS Done

DECLARE @state INT
SELECT @state = Pending FROM V_Execution_State
```

Comment: One problem with this approach though, is that if you decide to add another execution state you now have to not only change the view, but any code which relies on a static structure will be affected.

Comment: I wonder if there is some way you could use a Pivot to implement a view that changes automatically as the lookup table has additions made to it.

Comment: @AaronLS not sure if a PIVOT view would work, but you can generate such a view definition with a CTE: http://devio.wordpress.com/2012/08/28/generating-views-for-ms-sql-server-constants/

Comment: This is a truly amazing idea!!  I love it.  @TomH. Why wouldn't just changing the view work?  e.g. add `40 AS Aborted` to the view, wouldn't `SELECT @state = Pending FROM V_Execution_State` still work just fine?

Comment: Hate to bring up and old thread, but @devio, how do you execute the resulting SQL?  I tried following the stuff on your link and when i run `print @sql`, I do see the view script.  However, if I change it to `sp_executesql @sql`, I get "Incorrect syntax near 'sp_executesql'

Comment: do you miss a `GO` or an `EXECUTE`?

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would do it.  (Because it is much faster than your example)

```
UPDATE SomeTable
SET CurrentStatusID = [Status].[ID]
FROM SomeTable
 RIGHT JOIN [Status] ON [Name] = 'Acknowledged'
WHERE SomeTable.[ID] = @SomeID
```

(not tested could have typos)

Comment: I do this, except my lookup tables have a StatusText column which is used for display, and a UniqueName column which is used for hardcoded values.  This allows user requests that the displayed label be changed can be made without effecting the UniqueName which is referenced by hardcoded values.

Comment: The only reason I'm fearful of using this technique, is I don't know how much of a long term impact it will have on performance, to be doing querying on a string column instead of integer.

Comment: Ok this was 7 months ago.  As I remember my point was to use a join instead of a sub-query, which will be faster.  I've no idea where you get the idea that I'm querying on a string instead of an integer.  This will perform better than the example in the question since it is a join and not a sub-query.

Comment: Don't take offense Hogan.  Like I said, what you demonstrated is exactly what I currently do and I +1'd your answer.  Note that this is indeed a string: 'Acknowledged'.  One of the reasons I googled this was to see if anyone else had wondered the same as I and maybe benchmarked this vs. using the integer PK of the lookup table.

Comment: Ah I see now you are not the OP.  Performance:  The impact is small to non-existent for most look-up tables joined this way with less than say 500 or so rows since they will fit in memory during the join resolution.  But don't take my word, do some testing.

Answer (score 3):

Don't rely on IDENTITY for all of your IDs. When you have a lookup table that's going to be less than 50 rows for example, it's perfectly reasonable to either define those lookups as having specific IDs or use a string valued code for them. In either case, "hard-coding" is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 3):

One idea:

```
CREATE FUNC dbo.CONST_ACKNOWLEDGED()
RETURNS tinyint
AS
BEGIN
   RETURN 3
END
```

However, it only makes sense if you don't have autonumber, IMHO

Answer (score 1):

If your case is as simple as above, where an IsAcknowledged bit would work, I would go that route. I've never had any problems with that. If you have more complicated scenarios, where you would end up with a dozen bit fields, I don't see any problem using a "magic number" as long as you are fully in control of it. If you are worried about the identity column not mapping correctly when  you port the database, you could create another (non-identity) unique column with your ID values, integer or guid or whatever else would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If the 'Status' entity, which forms part of your domain model, has predefined values, some of which need to be handled in a specific manner by stored procedures, then it is perfectly OK to hardcode references to those specific values in your code. The problem here is that you are confusing what is potentially an abstract key (ID identity column) for a value that has a meaning in your domain model. Whilst it is OK to keep your ID identity column, you should use a meaningful attribute of your domain entity when referring to it in code, this can be the name, or it can be a numeric alias. But this numeric alias should be defined in your domain model, e.g. 3 means 'Acknowledged', and it should not be confused with the abstract ID field which, as you say, may be an identity column in some of your database instances.

Answer (score 0):

Well to start with, **Business Logic** should probably be avoided in the storage layer.

As this seems to be unavoidable when using a DB such as Sql Server where a lot of the *BL* can exists in the *DB*, I think you might rather revert to using *string IDs* rather than *auto IDs*.

*This will be a lot more managebale than auto ids, and can be handled in better ways, even when using the actual application layer.*

For instance using a .Net approach, a lot of the the unique string IDs can be store anywhere from the *config files*, to additional lookups using the selected db, XML files.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine

```
table dbo.Status
(
     Id int PK
    ,Description varchar
)
values
1, Received
2, Acknowledged
3, Under Review
etc
```

So, just

```
declare @StatusReceived int = 1
declare @StatusAcknowledged int = 2
declare @StatusUnderReview = 3
etc
```

As others mention, this assumes that IDENTITY is not set.

I too used to JOIN on lookup tables, but this keeps the SELECT shorter and easier to read.

This approach lends itself to automation, so I generate an entire table in a separate query, then copy over the elements I require (not all of them).

Answer (score 0):

We've taken a simple approach: Add a column named 'code' that contains a string that, once a record is created, is never changed.

If you hard-code the ID value you have problems - what if you deploy some functionality (such as stored procedures that hard-code an ID and assume you'll create the corresponding record with that ID value) to another database instance that already has that ID value used by another record? Or your code is deployed as SQL scripts that create the tables and data - and you cannot guarantee each deployment will generate ID values in the same way.

If you hard-code a field like 'Name' - there is a good chance 'Name' is displayed somewhere. What happens if the field is user-maintainable? If someone decides to change a Name value they break your procedures and functions. Even if it is not user-maintainable, some change in future will say 'We have to change the Name' and that will get done by SQL, breaking your dependent code and requiring a search for all dependencies, fixing same and testing all over again.

But if you create a 'Code' column that never changes, who cares if the Name value changes? Name is shown to the users - they can see what they want. Code is visible only to developers, and if absolutely necessary they can later comment the code to say 'Code value X refers to Y - the name changed as part of request number Z'.

Very simple approach.