# Is there a scalar database variable in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-design

We are creating a schema version for our database.  Right now we have a database table with a column version and a single row with the version.

Is it possible to make a scalar variable on the database, rather than a table?

Something like:

SET DBNAME.dbo.DBVersion = 1;

Comment: You may want to consider using [Extended Properties](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243(v=sql.105).aspx) for this purpose

Comment: Want to explain them in an answer @peterm?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the "Singleton Table" approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may consider to store a scalar value in an Extended Property attached to your database.

To add an extended property use [`sp_addextendedproperty`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180047%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'DBVersion', @value = '1';
```

To get a value of your property [`fn_listextendedproperty`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179853%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
SELECT value FROM fn_listextendedproperty(N'DBVersion', default, default, default, default, default, default);
```

Output:

```
Value
-----
    1
```

Further reading:

- [Using Extended Properties on Database Objects](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm guessing that people just go for tables because they are easy to query.  That definitely does the job.  I'll accept in a few days if no one comes out with anything more interesting than this.

Comment: I'd have performance reservations about this technique if it is being used frequently. I wouldn't trust the catalogs to be fast. I'd just create my own such table and function.

Comment: @Spence; people go for tables, because the idea of relational model is that all information should be stored in  relational variables (tables) and nothing else -- so called information principle
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd's_12_rules

Comment: the schema and any versioning used on it is metadata.  IF you wanted to take that to the nth degree you'd probably have a schema database that contains the definition of the database and you keep them in sync that way.  (Which is exactly what clearquest does...)

Comment: @usr extended properties are stored in `sys.extended_properties` table and you can query it with ordinary SELECTs if needed. Now as far performance is concerned as usual you never know until you actually benchmark it. Other than that it's only guesses and speculations.

Comment: @Spence Just curious did you decide what solution to go with?

Answer (score 2):

When I need to store constant values somewhere in the database for that that’s not necessarily related I usually end up with dbo.Config table that has one column for each cost that it needs to hold.

If you really want to store this somewhere outside the table you can consider extended properties, views, functions or stored procedures.

You can always create a function that looks like

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetSomeConst ()
RETURNS int
BEGIN
    return 12
END
```

Comment: Thats an interesting approach.  looks nice and functional and you should be able to map that into a DBML as well.  plus you can update the function return and it's not possible to change without using modification code, whereas the database table based answers can be modified by the user.

Comment: I was really torn, because I like this solution a lot.  I think that both this and the accepted answer are reasonable answers for the question.  this would be better in certain situations.

Answer (score 1):

For static (read-only) data, you can also define a single-row view:

```
CREATE VIEW V_Constants AS
SELECT '1' AS DBVersion
```

as sketched in an earlier [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2001498/21336)