# What is this join type: JOIN [Status] ON [Name] = 'Acknowledged'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I ran across a join style I had not seen before in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001375/sql-avoiding-hard-coding-or-magic-numbers) question:

```
UPDATE SomeTable
SET CurrentStatusID = [Status].[ID]
FROM SomeTable
 RIGHT JOIN [Status] ON [Name] = 'Acknowledged'
WHERE SomeTable.[ID] = @SomeID
```

Can someone explain this?  It seems to be a shortcut for a typically join.  In other words:

```
Select * from Items
JOIN ItemTypes on Code = 'TASK'
```

is a shortcut for:

```
Select * from Items i
JOIN ItemTypes it on i.ItemTypeId = it.Id
where it.Code = 'TASK'
```

Is that correct? Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, It's a near CROSS JOIN with a WHERE clause. [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3458296c832f91948b0d06d8c2041fce).

Comment: Have you tried running both queries, assuming you are in a position to do that?  You'd probably see that the result sets are not the same.

Comment: It's jibberish. Whomever wrote it didn't know what they were doing.  Change it to a CROSS JOIN and move the ON condition into the WHERE clause; it will do exactly the same thing but make more sense to read.

Comment: Yep Gibberish.
The right join would ordinarily preserve all rows from Status with `NULL` for `SomeTable` columns but the `SomeTable.[ID] = @SomeID` means it is an inner join anyway.
So basically it will find all rows from `[Status]` where `[Name] = 'Acknowledged'` and pick an arbitray `ID` from those and use that to Update `CurrentStatusID`. If there is no such row nothing is updated.

Comment: Got it, ok thank you very much, that clears that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incorrect, it is not a shortcut, at least not the one you think (to be precise: an `INNER JOIN` written like this could be considered a shortcut for a `CROSS JOIN` + `WHERE` here but I advise you to avoid thinking this is it).

In any type of `JOIN`, you are actually allowed to use constants, not only columns and for `OUTER JOIN`, the result will be different depending on where you write things.

Consider the following 2 examples:

```
WITH TableA(ID) AS (
    SELECT 1
    UNION
    SELECT 2
), TableB(ID, Type) AS (
    SELECT 1, 'Type1'
    UNION
    SELECT 1, 'Type2'
    UNION
    SELECT 2, 'Type2'
)
SELECT *
FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB ON TableA.ID = TableB.ID
WHERE Type= 'Type1'
```

And

```
WITH TableA(ID) AS (
    SELECT 1
    UNION
    SELECT 2
), TableB(ID, Type) AS (
    SELECT 1, 'Type1'
    UNION
    SELECT 1, 'Type2'
    UNION
    SELECT 2, 'Type2'
)
SELECT *
FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB ON TableA.ID = TableB.ID AND Type= 'Type1'
```

The first sample says: join everything but return only records containing Type1.
The second sample says: join only when you have Type1 on the right but return everything, even if you have failed to join (`LEFT OUTER JOIN`)